# How to refresh GXT's combo box after each call

Tags: gwt, combobox, gxt

I have a combo box. When I click a link, it opens a popup including a combo box (with data loaded from database). It always keeps data from the first call (it does not refresh).

How can I refresh this?

```java
VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();
vp.setSpacing(10);

ListStore<State> states = new ListStore<State>();
states.add(getStates());

ComboBox<State> combo = new ComboBox<State>();
combo.setEmptyText("Select a state...");
combo.setDisplayField("name");
combo.setWidth(150);
combo.setStore(states);
combo.setTypeAhead(true);
combo.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
vp.add(combo);
```

Comment: Do you recreate the combo box when opening the popup? Is `states.add(getStates());` the place that you update the combo box with values from the database? When do you update the `ListStore` backing the combo box? You should post more code to show some more context. At this point, I'd wager it should be `states.replaceAll(getStates());`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, that you are working with GXT and there fore are using the GXT Window class, you can do something like this:

```
myWindow.addBeforeShowHandler(new BeforeShowEvent.BeforeShowHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onBeforeShow(BeforeShowEvent event) {
        mxComoBox.clear();
    }
});
```

You see the old value, because a popup will be reused. so you have to clear the value of the combo, when the popup get visible.

This code should work with GXT 3.1.2. Older versions of GXT might have a different coding.

Hope that helps.